Why wont my Boolean modifier work to emboss this logo?
I'm trying to emboss a logo onto a bottle's cap. The logo was originally an SVG which I converted to a mesh and simplified it (using decimate modifier)

The selected mesh is what I have. Since I know how to use a Boolean modifier (or so I thought), I decided to select the cap, added the modifier and selected the Logo mesh. However, on adding the modifier and removing the mesh, i don't seem to see any embossing.
Am i using boolean wrong? Is there another way for embossing the logo?
Attaching the blend file below.
Thank you!


Check the normals (in "Viewport Overlays", select "Face Orientation"). You will see that the "LOGO" object is red, compared to the "CAP TOP" object that is blue (except the bottom doughnut...). In Edit Mode, go to "Mesh > Normals > Flip".

@StefLAncien Thank you!!! I cant believe I completely skipped this.

Because the logo is so squared up, subdividing the cap face and using a displacement modifier might give the best result. Even jus

I think you meant "deboss" instead of "emboss"?

@RonJensen yes.. just start with a 15x15 grid, (to give a margin of 1 on the outside), and extrude the appropriate selection of squares?

Try setting the Solver item in the Boolean modifier to "Fast".


Is there another way for embossing the logo?

In this case, the logo can be a selection of squares from a 15x15 grid, EZ   extruded. The perimeter of the grid can also be extruded, further down, and then AltN extruded out along normals with 'Offset Even' to the outer dimensions of your reference. The outer corners can be bevelled, and the topology cut as shown:

To hold under subdivision, all edges can be given a Bevel Weight of 0.5. then adjustments can be made either way, including knocking some loops out to 0, as shown, (on the right with a Bevel modifier, by weight):

Edges can be ShiftG selected by weight, so adjustments can be convenient.
The result subdivides well, if that's the direction you take it:


